# Bootstrap 5 table - full width on mobile, auto on desktop

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

How do I create a full width table using pure bootstrap classes on a mobile device, but `auto` on a desktop?

I tried to use:

```
<table class="table table-bordered w-md-auto w-100 text-start mb-2">
```

But the `w-100` class uses `!important` so it always overrides the desktop view to show it as 100% width instead of `auto`.
I tried using a combination of `w-100` and `w-auto` at different breakpoints but still can't get to show 100% wide on a mobile but auto on a desktop.

Note: I can't use any form of javascript, or add any custom CSS to override bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally the Boostrap way of doing it would be to rely on the default `width: 100%` applied to `.table`, overriding it for desktop with:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .table {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

You did mention you're not able to add custom CSS though; unfortunately it's not possible to add a `@media` query to an inline `style="..."` attribute on the table, so the only other way around this (gnarly as it is) is to include two versions of the same table (one for mobile, one for desktop), toggling the visibility using Bootstrap `d-{x}` display classes:

```
<table class="table table-bordered text-start mb-2 d-sm-none">
  <caption>
    Mobile table
  </caption>
  ...
</table>

<table class="table table-bordered text-start mb-2 w-auto d-none d-sm-table">
  <caption>
    Desktop table
  </caption>
  ...
</table>
```

Definitely not recommended though, due to the duplication of markup.  If you're limited in not being able to add a separate .CSS file, consider adding styling to the HTML itself, e.g.:

```
<style type="text/css">
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .table {
      width: auto;
    }
  }
</style>
```

If the concern is of custom CSS having unintended effects elsewhere, add either a custom class (e.g. `.my-responsive-table`) or a unique ID to the table, and target that instead of `.table`.